# How to copy a custom ios framework using plugin.xml on Phonegap 3

Tags: ios, xml, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am currently making a plugin for phonegap 3. I have a custom framework to copy using the source-file directive. In the plugin.xml I tried:

```
<source-file src="libs/ios/mylib.framework" />
```

but I get the error when I add the plugin to my project:

> mylib.framework is a directory (not copied)

I tried to copy the framework file by file but it is going in the wrong directory.

How can I copy a custom ios framework using the plugin.xml file?

Answer (score 24):

Good news: it seems that the Cordova folks are working on this as we speak.  There is a [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5238) as well as [a commit to GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman/commit/64fea2c878c3a03f37496af1c946c715aac11136) that claims to resolve this issue.  The `framework` tag will support the `custom="true"` attribute.  For example, here's how you could do it for the [AWS iOS SDK Runtime framework](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/):

```
<framework src="src/ios/Frameworks/AWSRuntime.framework" custom="true" />
```

**UPDATE:** It seems that this change made it into the current stable release of Cordova on 11/29/2013 (two days ago).  Just update your Cordova and Plugman binaries and you should be good to go.

```
$ npm update -g cordova  # if using `cordova plugin add xyz`
$ npm update -g plugman  # if using `plugman install --platform x --project y --plugin z`
```

Comment: `custom="true"` works like a charm. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the **binary file** (*who should be in **"mylib.framework/Versions/A/"***) and the **headers** ( *".h" who should be in **"mylib.framwork/Versions/A/Headers"***)

like this

```
<source-file src="libs/ios/mylib.framework/Versions/A/mylibBinary" framework="true" />
<header-file src="libs/ios/mylib.framework/Version/A/Headers/mylibHeader.h" />
...
```

You also have to add the dependencies manually, IE.: this framework needs the iOS `AVFoundation.framework` so, you need to add this too.

```
<framework src="AVFoundation.framework" />
```

One more thing you have to know, if you want to submit this plugin to PhoneGap.

### Plugin Submission Guidelines

> Any application that contains binary libraries will be rejected. This is because we need to be able to see exactly what is in a plugin as part of our code review process. So when submitting a plugin make sure that it doesn’t contain binary libraries. ([PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/04/plugin-submission-guidelines/))

Comment: This will not generate the necessary dependencies in the project.pbxproj file

Answer (score 0):

Use `<framework src="libs/ios/mylib.framework" />`.

Comment: Have you find the solution @poiuytrez?

Comment: @ShashankTomar No, I have not.

Comment: @poiuytrez we eventually converted it into a static library and copied it using source file tag