# How to Add a Third Party Framework to a Cordova 3.0 Custom Plugin?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, icenium

I'm trying to create a cordova plugin with a third party framework (in this case AdColony.framework) https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to add this framework using the plugin.xml ([Plugin Specification](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification)).

I tried to include the file as a framework through

```
<framework src="src/ios/libs/AdColony.framework" />
```

OR

```
<source-file src="src/ios/libs/AdColony.framework" framework="true" />
```

But both didn't worked. Please help me to figure this out. Any suggestions and response will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Custom frameworks work with Cordova 3.4

`<framework src="relative/path/to/my.framework" custom="true" />`

Comment: Is it possible to add a framework hosted at some url? My plugin requires a lot of 3rd party frameworks and overall size exceeds the limit at build.phonegap.com

Comment: where do u add this tag

Comment: I am using cordova 6.2.0 and this solution is not enough. Custom frameworks must be embedded into the app. There is a solution by creating a hook but I wonder if there is an official "Cordova" way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650522/custom-cordova-plugin-add-framework-to-embedded-binaries

Answer (score 5):

This answer suggests it is not possible: [How to copy a custom ios framework using plugin.xml on Phonegap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653413/how-to-copy-a-custom-ios-framework-using-plugin-xml-on-phonegap-3) which suggests converting the framework into a static library and using that.

This thread might be useful to you: http://osdir.com/ml/phonegap/2013-11/msg00176.html

And you might want to follow along with this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5238  , which appears to address what you want and was recently merged (so might make it into 3.2 or 3.3).  It also has a workaround:

```
1. a <resource-file> tag to copy the .framework folder and include in Xcode
2. a <framework> tag to add it to the "Link Binary with Libraries" section of the Build Phases of the project
```

(You can include default frameworks with the `framework` tag (of course, that is not what you are asking).)