# Cordova plugin ios for telerik : Add Custom framework to embedded binaries

Tags: ios, cordova, telerik

I'm trying to create a cordova iOS plugin for a telerik ios app.
To integrate the custom(PressReader_SDK) framework embedded binaires i'm using this method :

[Custom Cordova Plugin: Add framework to "Embedded Binaries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650522/custom-cordova-plugin-add-framework-to-embedded-binaries)

The problem i'm encountering is that when i try to use the plugin in a cordova app it works fine but when i add the same plugin in telerik app, i get the error "image not found" this error occurs when cordova plugin isn't loading the embedded binaires.

I've searched all over cordova documentation but i can't find any way to make it work.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like I'm not the only one to encounter this frustrating problem. The issue is this: Your using the solution found in the question [Custom Cordova Plugin: Add framework to “Embedded Binaries”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650522/custom-cordova-plugin-add-fr) and it's only working in a plain Cordova app, but not a Telerik app. That's because the this solution relies on using custom hooks in the plugins `config.xml` and [Telerik doesn't allow custom hooks](http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-ios-plugin-(embedded-binaries)#GXpuiwEDkkqILemSqU-PHg). So your hook actually isn't running at all and your no better off than when you started. I'm not aware of any work around for this problem and I've created a SO question to find out if *anybody* does ([Telerik AppBuilder and Embedded Binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921936/telerik-appbuilder-and-embedded-binaries)). Hope we get some results!