# Cordova - Include .framework (swift 3) dependency as plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, swift3, native

I have native code developed on swift 3. Basically this code generate a library with the .framework extension.
I want to use this library as plugin on a apache cordova application but I cannot make it work.
I looked over internet and there is a few post including this ([Custom Cordova Plugin: Add framework to "Embedded Binaries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650522/custom-cordova-plugin-add-framework-to-embedded-binaries)) but this option's doesn't work with the latest versions of cordova (6+).

If I put the .swift files individually over my cordova project I can use it, so I think there is a problem to get the correct communication between cordova and the .framework library.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Hey @HolloW, any updates on this? Did you achieve integrating your swift custom framework with cordova application using plugin?

Answer (score 4):

Latest Cordova Version is 8.0.0

Try like this:

```
<framework src="relative/path/to/my.framework" custom="true" embed="true" />
```

Comment: I already tried this with cordova 7 and doesn't work. Do you have any clue about this over cordova 7?

Comment: Looks like you are facing this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13533. There seem to be a workaround, to add your framework twice, once with custom and embed and another without them.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with @jcesarmobile's answer. Also if you are looking for an elaborate steps for making cordova plugin with custom iOS framework, then you gotta look at this [link](http://www.codepool.biz/cordova-plugin-custom-ios-framework.html).

It provides step by step explanation of creating a cordova plugin with Dynamsoft iOS barcode SDK. Hope this will help you to start off.

Comment: Yes, I already saw that article and doesn't work with cordova 7.